# Post of data from ListBox is not being rendered to the database

Tags: django, listbox

I have an app that takes as one of the form fields a multiple listbox. The data is defined on the html page as "temp_groups", then in the view.py the form.cleaned_data['actual field'] is set to the extracted temp field.  The data extracted appears correct (2,3) and looking at the same field after the form.save() is executed looks correct.  But the data is not rendered to the database that way.  It is using the value set on the actual "hidden" field on the html page.  Here is the code

Tried using the actual field name (group_members) but the result is only the last value selected from the list is actually posted.

Also tried setting up a widget on the forms.py file where the data used in supplying comes from the query of the User object (auth_user).  But this had no impact.

url.py

```py
   urlpatterns = [..
      path('newgroups/', views.newgroups, name='newgroups'),
```

forms.py

```py
   class QueryGroupsForm(forms.ModelForm):
       class Meta:
          model = QueryGroups
          fields = ['group_name',
                    'group_desc',
                    'group_members',
                   ]
```

models.py

```py
   class QueryGroups(models.Model):
      group_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
      group_desc = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
      group_members = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

querygroups.html

```html
   <div class="col-3">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="temp_members" class="" style="font-weight: bold;">Group Members<label>
       <select id="temp_members" name="temp_members" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
          {% for nextUser in users %}
            <option value="{{nextUser.id}}">{{nextUser.username}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
       </select>
       <input type="hidden" name="group_members" id="group_members" value="TBD">
     </div>
   </div>
```

views.py

```py
   def newgroups(request):
       if request.method == "POST":
          group_form = QueryGroupsForm(request.POST)
          user_list = request.POST.getlist('temp_members')
          users_of_group = ""
          for next_user in user_list:
              users_of_groups += next_user + ","
          list_len = len(users_of_groups)
          users_of_group = users_of_group[:list_len - 1]
          if group_form.is_valid():
              group_form.cleaned_data['group_members'] = str(user_of_group)
              group_form.save()
              post_list = group_form.cleaned_data['group_members']
              return HttpResponse("user_of_group: " + users_of_group + " post_list: " + str(post_list))
```

What is presented on the HttpResponse is "users_of_group: 2,3 post_list: 2,3".  However, what is in the group_members field in the database is the value "TBD" which is set as the hidden field in the html file.

Comment: Define `temp_members` as a field on your ModelForm and leave the hard work to Django

Comment: Thanks for your thought but I had already tried that.  The problem is it only retains the last of whatever values I select from the list box